# Regular Expressions for specific number patterns

Tags: regex, vbscript

I  have an invoice in readable form. I need to extract PO number from the invoice. The PO numbers come in a particular format `(26123456, 26234567)`. It starts with `26` and has `6` numbers following it. I am trying to extract it using regular expressions.

I have passed this as my parameters.

`[26]\d{6,6}` also I have tried this `^[26]\d{6,6}`

However, the problems I am facing are:

If the PO number is `26454545` and before the PO number there are other numbers in the invoice such as Telephone numbers which have in them a substring with `26`, its extracting that as well. For ex. `12345678987` this number is being extracted as well since there is 2 and 6 present in the substring.

Comment: `\d{6}` is the same as `\d{6,6}`. Also, `[26]` matches *either* 2 *or* 6, not 26. So `[000]` will match *either* 0, *or* 0, *or* 0... so do you see the problem?

Comment: Yeah i did Jerry, thanks for the comment. It works alright now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the character class and add word boundaries.

```
\b26\d{6}\b
```

- `[26]` will match a single character from the given list whether it may be 2 or 6. To match a number 26, just use the number as it is.
- By adding `\b` at the start and at the end helps to match a complete number. Since `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character. You could also use assertions here like `(?<!\d)26\d{6}(?!\d)` .

> There is another pattern that i want to extract 12300012345. after the first three numbers there are always 3 zeros followed by 5 numbers.

```
\b\d{3}000\d{5}\b
```

If you want to combine the both, then you need to use the regex alternation operator `|`

```
\b26\d{6}\b|\b\d{3}000\d{5}\b
```

Comment: There is another pattern that i want to extract 12300012345. after the first three numbers there are always 3 zeros followed by 5 numbers. This is what i have \d{3,3}[000]\d{5,5}